# How to pass value from one method to another in django

Tags: django

**views.py**
This is method in views i want to pass project_id,feature_name value from passReviewerProjFeature to sortbyName

```
def passReviewerProjFeature(request):

                testcase_object_array=""

                if request.method == 'POST':
                    reviewer_name = request.POST['reviewer_id']
                    project_id = request.POST['tcrproject_id']
                    feature_name = request.POST['tcrsearch_id']
                    id=FeatureCache.objects.filter(name=feature_name)
          testcase_object_array=TestcaseCache.objects.filter(project=project_id).filter(feature=id)

                return render(request,'tcrform.html',{'form':TestcaseCacheForm(),'testcase_object_array':testcase_object_array})
```

Here in sortbyName method I want the values which are taken from html page assReviewerProjFeature

```
def sortbyName(request):
```

Here I want the project_id,feature_name variable value in this function from passReviewerProjFeature method

Answer (score 0):

Try this way,

```
def sortbyName(request, project_id, feature_name):
     do your logic here
     pass

def passReviewerProjFeature(request):

      testcase_object_array=""

      if request.method == 'POST':
            reviewer_name = request.POST['reviewer_id']
            project_id = request.POST['tcrproject_id']
            feature_name = request.POST['tcrsearch_id']
            id=FeatureCache.objects.filter(name=feature_name)

            testcase_object_array=TestcaseCache.objects.filter(project=project_id).filter(feature=id)
            sortbyName(request, project_id, feature_name) --> My Edit

      return render(request,'tcrform.html',{'form':TestcaseCacheForm(),'testcase_object_array':testcase_object_array})
```

Comment: did you call the `sortbyName` from `passReviewerProjFeature` ?. Please see my post.

Comment: TypeError at /sortbyName/

sortbyName() takes exactly 3 arguments (1 given)

It give me this error